# Values in ListView are reset once I close and reopen Android app

Tags: android, database, listview

In my MainActivity I have a dialog that comes up and the user inputs their information in two EditTexts. The first EditText is their name and the second one is an amount the person owes. This data is then saved to the database and is shown in my listView. When I close the app and reopen it, i fetch the values from the database, but for some reason each view is numbered from 1 to how many times I input data, and the numerical data is all set to 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 FloatingActionButton fab;
 private ListView listView;
 private ArrayAdapter<OweInfo> adapter;

private PayUpDatabaseHelper db = new PayUpDatabaseHelper(this);
Context context;

ArrayList<OweInfo> owesList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this.getApplicationContext();
    owesList = db.getAllOwes();
    adapter = new OwesAdapter(this, R.layout.payup_list_row, owesList);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    if(adapter != null && listView != null )
    {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


   fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //fire up the dialog!
            startDialog();
        }
    });

}

public void startDialog()
{
    //Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new        AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    //get layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    //inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_owe_dialog,null);
        builder.setView(view)

            //add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    EditText nameEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.name_edit_text);
                    EditText amountEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.amount_edit_text);

                    String getNameText = nameEditText.getText().toString();
                    int getAmountText = Integer.parseInt(amountEditText.getText().toString());

                    OweInfo owes = new OweInfo(getNameText, getAmountText);
                    db.addOwe(owes);
                    adapter.add(owes);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

                builder.create().show();
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


 }
```

Here's the code for my database

```
public class PayUpDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
 public SQLiteDatabase db;

//Database name
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.ch1bi.payup";

//Database version
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

//PayUp table name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "owes";

//PayUp table column names
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";

public PayUpDatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

//Create table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

//code for upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

public void addOwe(OweInfo info)
{
    //open database to write to it
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, info.getNameExtra());
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, info.getAmountExtra());

    //insert values into row
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    //close connection after writing to db
    db.close();
}

public ArrayList<OweInfo> getAllOwes()
{
    ArrayList<OweInfo> oweList = new ArrayList<>();

    String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            OweInfo owes = new OweInfo();
            owes.setNameExtra(cursor.getString(0));
            owes.setAmountExtra(cursor.getInt(1));
            oweList.add(owes);
        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();

    return oweList;

}

}
```

My custom class

```
public class OweInfo
{
private String nameExtra;
private int amountExtra;

public OweInfo()
{

}

public OweInfo(String name, int amount)
{
    this.nameExtra = name;
    this.amountExtra = amount;
}

public String getNameExtra()
{
    return this.nameExtra;
}

public void setNameExtra(String nameExtra)
{
    this.nameExtra = nameExtra;
}

public int getAmountExtra()
{
    return this.amountExtra;
}

public void setAmountExtra(int amountExtra)
{
    this.amountExtra = amountExtra;
}



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `amount` column in your database as `TEXT`, but you are fetching its value as integer and that's giving you '0' .

You have to modify your fetch query  as follows -

```
 owes.setAmountExtra(cursor.getString(1));
```

Comment: In my OweInfo class, I have the amount set as an int, so cursor.getString(1) wouldn't work for me. What would you propose I do?

Comment: In that case , you can change the database structure, making `amount` column as integer.

Comment: I made the amount column an Integer. I uninstalled the app and reinstalled it, and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Please extract and  verify that your database contains proper values .

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. In my database class I changed the line

```
String selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME; 

                        To

String[] tableColumns = new String[]{"name", "amount"};
```

then I ran a query

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("owes", tableColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Previously, I was selecting all the columns including the _id column that automatically updates whenever you add data to your table. That's the reason all of my views were numbered and the other view was 0. I was querying all columns and being that I had two TextViews I was displaying the id in the first TextView  and the name of the person in the second, that's why the value was 0. So it was best that I specified the exact columns I wanted to query.